# Create ten instances of a class simultaneously using threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand threads in Java. As an exercise, I created an Ice Cream class as follows.

```
public class ThreadIceCream {

private String flavor = "";
private String[] specialFlavors = { "Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Butter Pecan", "Strawberry", "Chocolate Chip", "Cherry", "Coffee" };
    // Constructor for ThreadIceCream class
public ThreadIceCream() {       
    int randInt = (int) (Math.random() * specialFlavors.length);
    flavor = specialFlavors[randInt];
    System.out.println("Enjoy your " + flavor + " IceCream!");
} }
```

The ThreadIceCream class is a simple class that creates an IceCream object with a random flavor every time the class is initialized. Here is the TestStub I am using.

```
public class TestStub {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ThreadIceCream Th1 = new ThreadIceCream();
    ThreadIceCream Th2 = new ThreadIceCream();

} }
```

Now I want to create 10 Icecreams (i.e. Create 10 instances of the ThreadIceCream class simultaneously) and I want to use threads in Java to do this. I tried a few things but they were no were close.

Comment: Ever heard of looping? And BTW, why do you need threads here?

Comment: I know looping that would create 10 instances one after the other. I want to do it using threads to learn how threads work and start of with to simple example to understand better.

Comment: [Google is your friend.](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+threads+tutorial)

Comment: It would be great if you could help me figure this out instead of giving trivial advice.

Comment: It would be great if you learned to use a search engine to answer questions that have already been asked an answered thousands of times. Examples of how to create a simple threaded application in Java are a dime a dozen, and it would be a waste of time for anyone to reproduce one here.

Comment: Create a paused [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) (scroll down the explanation, it's listed as an example).  Create the executor, pause it, add your tasks and then resume it. There is no way you can create threads absolutely simultaneously (caveat, I have now doubt you could start 10 threads that could be triggered to each start a new single thread each at almost the same time, but is it really worth the effort), they will all start slight after each other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's not really that hard:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    threads[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ThreadIceCream tic = new ThreadIceCream();
                    }
                 });
    threads[i].start();
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    threads[i].join();
}
```

Sure, this won't do much because the work performed by each thread is so small that the overhead to start the threads is actually higher, but whatever.

You should also learn to use the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for higher efficiency. Pure threads are heavyweight and are rarely a good solution for anything, especially in groups. Here's an `ExecutorService` version of the above:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    exec.submit(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ThreadIceCream tic = new ThreadIceCream();
                    }
                });        
}

exec.shutdown();
exec.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Here we are creating a pool of 10 threads and submitting 10 tasks. The threads are recycled betweeen task executions, so only 10 threads are ever created, no matter how many tasks you submit. Since the tasks are so small several tasks may even be executed on the same thread, but that's actually a good thing.

Comment: Thanks Tudor, I too read some articles on a blog. I get a hang of it now. I'll try it and see if I can get it right. Thanks for the response!